# GROUP BY - How can I optimize this MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, group-by, query-optimization

```
SELECT results.idpatient AS nhs_number, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, STR_TO_DATE(results.dob,'%Y-%m-%d'), CURDATE()) AS age, most_overdue.days_overdue,
most_overdue.current_status, most_overdue.action, indications.associated_indications
FROM mytable AS results
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        idpatient,
        MAX(days_overdue) as days_overdue,
        SUBSTRING(MAX(CONCAT(LPAD(days_overdue, 11, '0'), current_status)), 12) AS current_status,
        SUBSTRING(MAX(CONCAT(LPAD(days_overdue, 11, '0'), action)), 12) AS action
    FROM
        mytable
    GROUP BY
        idpatient
) AS most_overdue
ON results.idpatient = most_overdue.idpatient
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT idpatient, action, GROUP_CONCAT(indication SEPARATOR ',') as associated_indications
    FROM mytable
    GROUP BY idpatient, action
) AS indications
ON results.idpatient = indications.idpatient AND most_overdue.action = indications.action
GROUP BY results.idpatient
LIMIT 0,100;
```

**The above query takes ~4s to run on my big MySQL DB, and the issue seems to be the GROUP BYs.**

See a simplified Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=d1b029ff180c3acd74f0c141859cd4f6) .

I read MySQL's page on optimizing GROUP BY, but this doesn't seem to cover its use in conjunction with GROUP_CONCAT.

The schema is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `idpatient` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `indication` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `action` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `current_status` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `query_type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `last_date` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `days_overdue` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dob` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idpatient`,`indication`,`action`),
  KEY `action_idx` (`action`),
  KEY `indication_idx` (`indication`),
  KEY `idpatient_action_idx` (`idpatient`,`action`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

EXPLAIN tells me the indication_idx and idpatient_action_idx are in use when running the slow query.

Any help towards getting this under 1s would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Unrelated, but your query is not valid for standard SQL. It will not compile with sql_mode=only_full_group_by. For starters, there may be several  associated_indications for each idpatient, which one do you want in your result (which action?)

Comment: Thanks, Lennart! I thought the line `ON results.idpatient = indications.idpatient AND results.action = indications.action` would ensure that only the `indications.action` action would be included in the result? If not, would you be so kind as to help me achieve that outcome?

Comment: I added a temporary answer to try to straighten out the question marks

Comment: A LIMIT clause without an ORDER BY clause allows the database server to return arbitrarily chosen (unpredictable) rows.  If I were you I'd be really careful about that sort of thing when handling other peoples' health records.

Comment: @O.Jones, thanks, rest assured no real health records will be touched by this SQL!

Comment: Consider using www.eversql.com to analyze your query and they will propose indexes required and more readable query structure.  The will provide one free analysis if you will register with them.

Answer (score 0):

Does this query give the correct result (I assume it is still slow)?

```
SELECT results.idpatient AS nhs_number
     , most_overdue.days_overdue
     , most_overdue.current_status
     , most_overdue.action
     , indications.associated_indications
FROM (
    SELECT distinct idpatient
    FROM mytable
) AS results
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        idpatient,
        MAX(days_overdue) as days_overdue,
        SUBSTRING(MAX(CONCAT(LPAD(days_overdue, 11, '0'), current_status)), 12) AS current_status,
        SUBSTRING(MAX(CONCAT(LPAD(days_overdue, 11, '0'), action)), 12) AS action
    FROM
        mytable
    GROUP BY
        idpatient
) AS most_overdue
ON results.idpatient = most_overdue.idpatient
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT idpatient, action, GROUP_CONCAT(indication SEPARATOR ',') as associated_indications
    FROM mytable
    GROUP BY idpatient, action
) AS indications
ON results.idpatient = indications.idpatient AND most_overdue.action = indications.action;
```

This may be a cleaner way to derive the current_status/action associated with most days_overdue:

```
SELECT results.idpatient AS nhs_number
     , (most_overdue.days_overdue)
     , (results.current_status)
     , results.action
     , indications.associated_indications
FROM mytable AS results
JOIN (
    SELECT 
        idpatient,
        MAX(days_overdue) as days_overdue
    FROM mytable
    GROUP BY idpatient
) AS most_overdue
    ON results.idpatient = most_overdue.idpatient
    AND results.days_overdue = most_overdue.days_overdue
JOIN (
    SELECT idpatient, action, GROUP_CONCAT(indication SEPARATOR ',') as associated_indications
    FROM mytable
    GROUP BY idpatient, action
) AS indications
     ON results.idpatient = indications.idpatient 
     AND results.action = indications.action
-- GROUP BY results.idpatient, results.action     
ORDER BY results.idpatient;
```

I can't help thinking that it should be possible to remove at least 1 access against mytable, but right now I don't see how

Comment: indication1,indication2,indication3 - if I understand the question correctly?

Comment: @DuncanWare It would be much easier if you provide a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=3bbebf7efe9f01901d41d4013bf96b4c). Add some data example and expected result.

Comment: @Lennart, apologies! I just realised that the query I shared originally is not equivalent to the query I'm actually having issues with - I've updated the query in the original question accordingly.

I would like to retrieve all the `indication` fields associated with the `action` defined in the question as `results.action` and concatenate them into the field `associated_indications`. The query provided returns the data I want, only it does so too slowly...

Comment: @ErgestBasha, the query provided returns the data I want, only it does so too slowly - do you have any suggestions on how to refactor the query to improve performance?

Comment: Why are you grouping by idpatient in your modified query?

Comment: and what version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @Lennart, without it I get duplicate rows. Have just confirmed that making the original SELECT a SELECT DISTINCT also works. Do you think these duplicates speak to an issue with the logic?

Comment: @Lennart version '5.7.12'

Comment: Can you produce a fiddle with a minimal example of the duplicates?

Comment: Yes, the duplicate rows show a problem with your query's logic.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=d1b029ff180c3acd74f0c141859cd4f6

Comment: Thanks, the dublicates origins from the outer select, as an example it contributes with 4 rows where idpatient = 1 in the result. I'll see if I can re-phrase it

Comment: @Lennart - it does! Thanks so much, I really appreciate all your help. Now I just need to get the time down a bit, although maybe this is an inherently slow procedure?

Comment: Your construction `SUBSTRING(MAX(CONCAT(LPAD(days_overdue, 11, '0'), current_status)), 12) AS current_status` is it to get the status for each idpatient with the most days_overdue?

Comment: @Lennart correct, it does look like a silly way to achieve this but I couldn't find a more concise/performant alternative - do you know of one?

Comment: ok, I'll have a look. If only you were on 8 everything would have been much easier.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, without any evidence to support my guess, that you want your resultset to show the hundred lowest `idpatient` values.

Your query is made of two subqueries and a main query. Let's start with the **first subquery**.

```sql
SELECT 
  idpatient,
  MAX(days_overdue) as days_overdue,
  SUBSTRING(MAX(CONCAT(LPAD(days_overdue, 11, '0'), current_status)), 12) AS current_status,
  SUBSTRING(MAX(CONCAT(LPAD(days_overdue, 11, '0'), action)), 12) AS action
FROM    mytable
GROUP BY idpatient
ORDER BY idpatient
LIMIT    0, 100;
```

Notice that I included your LIMIT clause in this subquery.

This subquery will benefit from the following [covering index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/glossary.html#glos_covering_index).

```sql
ALTER TABLE mytable 
  ADD INDEX patient_days_status_activity
            (idpatient, days_overdue, current_status, action);
```

The *first two* columns of the index support your `GROUP BY` operation. If your table is smaller than something like 100k rows you can omit the *last two* columns from that index; they only serve to make the lookup of `current_status` and `action` a bit faster.

With the index in place examine the performance of that subquery; look at `EXPLAIN` output. Convince yourself it's fast enough for your purposes.

Now for the **second subquery**. Your `idpatient_action_idx` index helps with this query. You should add the ORDER BY / LIMIT clauses to it. You could also add `indication` to that index to make it into a covering index.

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
  DROP INDEX idpatient_action_idx,
  ADD INDEX idpatient_action_idx (idpatient, action, indication);
```

Make the index change if you want to. Then examine the performance of that subquery as well.   If both the subqueries have acceptable performance your main query probably will too.

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful and informative :)

Comment: Unfortunately, these optimizations only reduced query time by 200ms, I suppose it might just be an unavoidably expensive query :(